# Need for a customizable Unmanned Ground Vehicle (UGV) to work in ROS and Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, uav, hector, husky, jackal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, Please help...

I am working on a project where I need UGV designed in ROS and can be simulated in Gazebo and (Preferably contain some sensors such as camera, ultrasonic and Lidar or such sensors can be added to it), and to have an interface with a joystick.
also I need to change the shape of this vehicle to a custom made one that I build using .dae file.

I was looking for such vehicle and I found ( Husky , Grizzly , and Jackal) but all are not customizable as I could not neither change there physical appearance nor to add some sensors to them.

1- Husky ( http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/Husky )
2- Grizzly (http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/Grizzly)
3- Jackal (http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/Jackal)

Please if you know such vehicle that I can install and use or if you have a useful suggestions then let me know.
I could not build my own because I am still a beginner in this field and I need a moving vehicle (with dynamic model) which is difficult for me to build.

Many thanks in advance,
Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251253/need-for-a-customizable-unmanned-ground-vehicle-(ugv)-to-work-in-ros-and-gazebo./) by [max9090](https://answers.ros.org/users/26925/max9090/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can always start with the models for those vehicles and then modify them for your simulation including editing the meshes to make your own custom version. And you can definitely add sensors to them or any other model in simulation. https://answers.ros.org/question/51773/adding-sensors-to-gazebo-from-scratch/ https://answers.ros.org/question/210695/adding-a-camera-to-a-model-in-gazebo-beginner/

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0